# Calculate trajectory given a coordinate and angle

Tags: math, geometry, angle

Given the following:
- starting point (coordinate)
- angle (degree)
- velocity

.. I'd like to calculate the given trajectory.
For example for the image below w/ velocity 1: (10,10) (9,9) (8,8) (7,7) ..

It should be able to move in all directions.
How can I calculate it?

[image: example]

Comment: In the 2D and 3D world that I live in, velocity vectors only have 2 or 3 components.  What's that "velocity" that you posted?  It's a high school trig problem if you pose it properly.

Comment: It's a **2D world**, the **velocity is** basically the **speed** it travels at.

Comment: Yes, I get it.  (No need for "basically".)  I'm saying that velocity vector should have two numbers in it, and no more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an angle and a speed (scalar), the components in the x- and y-directions are easy:

```
vx = (speed)*cos(angle)

vy = (speed)*sin(angle)
```

Angle needs to be in radians for most languages, not degrees.  Make sure you convert it.

So if you have a point (ux, uy) at time t1, then the position at time t2 is:

```
ux(t2) = ux(t1) + vx*(t2-t1)

uy(t2) = uy(t1) + vy*(t2-t1)
```

Let's see what it looks like in Java:

```
/**
 * Method for updating a position giving speed, angle, and time step
 * @param original coordinates in x, y plane
 * @param speed magnitude; units have to be consistent with coordinates and time
 * @param angle in radians
 * @param dtime increment in time 
 * @return new coordinate in x, y plane
 */
public Point2D.Double updatePosition(Point2D.Double original, double speed, double angle, double dtime) {
    Point2D.Double updated = new Point2D.Double();    
    updated.x = original.x + speed*Math.cos(angle)*dtime;
    updated.y = original.y + speed*Math.sin(angle)*dtime;    
    return updated;
}
```

Comment: Could you put that in C# or Java syntax please?
I don't quite follow.

Comment: how did you come out with the equations?

Comment: Standard 2D vector mathematics, ordinary derivatives from calculus, and finite differences.

Comment: I see, I think I understand, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed